# Unable to update modified entities

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've got an aggregate for a specific type of entity which is stored in a collection inside the aggregate. Now I'd like to add a new entry of that type and update the aggregate afterwards, however Entity Framework never updates anything!

#### Model

```
public class MyAggregate {
    protected ICollection<MyEntity> AggregateStorage { get; set; }

    public void AddEntity(MyEntity entity) {
        // some validation
        AggregateStorage.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

#### API Controller

```
[UnitOfWork, HttpPost]
public void UpdateMyEntity(int aggregateId, MyEntityDto dto) {
    var aggregate = _aggregateRepository.Find(aggregateId);
    aggregate.AddEntity(...// some mapping of the dto).

    _aggregateRepository.Update(aggregate);
}
```

#### EF Update

```
EntitySet.Attach(aggregate);
Context.Entry(aggregate).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

*(Please note that there's an unit of work interceptor on the API action who fires `DbContext.SaveChanges()` after successful execution of the method.)*

Funny thing is, the update never get's executed by EF. I've added a log interceptor to the `DbContext` to see what's going on sql-wise and while everything else works fine, an update statement never occurs.

Comment: Is `MyAggregate` relationship with `MyEntity` 1:Many?  If so, there's nothing to update for `MyAggregate`, you're actually adding a new `MyEntity`.

Comment: @CharlesMager So then how can I commit these changes to the database? When I query it after I added the entity (yes, adding a new is the intention), nothing has changed.

Comment: This should just work if you've got change tracking on, and you shouldn't need `Update` or any attaching or changing of state.  Can you add the full code for `Find` and `Update`?

Comment: @CharlesMager: http://pastebin.com/NkieZmC2 (just an excerpt, but all relevant parts should be there..)

Comment: No, please, no pastebin. Include relevant code in the question itself. It should be clear what exactly `aggregate` contains after calling `Find`.

Comment: @GertArnold CharlesMager asked for the full code for Find/Update, not what the aggregate contains. I created a pastebin because they got a more easily readable layout than having a uneccesary long SO question.

Comment: Questions can be too long. They can also be too short. They should be self-contained anyway. That aside, the pastebin code still doesn't show what `Find` does, because it refers to other invisible parts in your code. Neither is it clear where/when you actually call SaveChanges. One hint: setting an entity's state only affects its scalar properties, not its navigation properties.

Comment: @GertArnold You'll find the actual find method (heh..) in the pastebin (called QuerySingle). The 'Find' in the code above is just pseudo code to describe the general problem. Also, in the question above I stated that I use an intercepted unit of work to call SaveChanges, it should be obvious how it works (execute target invocation, commit on success). Anyway, you're right with your hint, I did not know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053660/aggregate-root-support-in-entity-framework) in detached scenario (either aggregate is not loaded by EF or it is loaded by different context instance) you must attach the aggregate to context instance and tell it exactly what did you changed, set state for every entity and independent association in object graph.

You must either use eager loading and load all data together at the beginning and
instead of changing the state of aggregate, change the state of entities:

```
foreach(var entity in aggregate.AggregateStorage)
{
    if(entity.Id == 0)
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
}
```

Comment: This! It seems like the entities from the aggregates collection were indeed not attached, so EF had absolutely no clue about any changes.